# Annoying format for functions

Tags: java, coding-style, try-catch

I have started working with a large code base, and a lot of the code has been set up with a strange format for functions. more or less every function has the following format

```
foo(){
    trace_messages()
    // this is what I don't get
    try{
          // all code goes here
    } finally {
          trace_messages()
    }
}
```

I can't see any sense behind the insistence on wrapping more or less the entire work of function in a try. Is this some sort of 'best practice' that I never got told about?

EDIT:

perhaps  I should have stated, but the two calls to `trace_messages()` are actually different sections of code, but more or less the same... if you follow my meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention of that code was to make sure that `trace_messages()` was guaranteed to executed in the beginning and before the end of `foo()`.

`finally` is guaranteed to execute both in case everything runs fine, and if the code inside `try` fails miserably with some nasty uncaught runtime exception.

I agree that the format chosen to achieve this intention is not of the best, normally that is done with some sort of AOP, in Spring you would wrap `foo()` into [Around advice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

Answer (score 1):

Find the definition of `trace_messages()`, and you will see what the last guy was trying to do. If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, right-click on `trace_messages()` and there should be an option to jump directly to the definition.

Comment: And by the way, no, it's not some kind of 'best practice'.

Comment: Agree. The coder is trying to ensure that `trace_messages` will always be called at the beginning and before exiting each method. Sounds like AOP to me.

Comment: True, it's not a best practice. It's not even an OK practice. Besides, all code that runs inside a `try` block is slower.

Comment: I know how to find the deceleration / definition of a function. I don't see what relevance this has

Comment: @SoboLAN: "all code that runs inside a try block is slower" - With the scope *ALL* this statement is false.

Comment: @thecoshman, obviously the previous developer wants to guarantee that some code will run at the beginning and end of each method, but why? You have to look at what the code is actually doing to understand why he wrote all his functions like this. Is it for logging, to help debug? Looking at the definition of `trace_messages()` will tell you the answer.